# What's is the best options for PM2 ecosystem config

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm using PM2 for my NodeJS express application on the production. When reading the PM2 docs, we have 2 options for the ecosystem config file

- https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/: for load balancing
- https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/memory-limit/: for auto restarting

I don't know what is the best number for `cluster_mode` instances and the `max_memory_restart` options.

Does anyone has experience with this, it would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

`max_memory_restart`: This totally depends on the type of application and average memory usage.
`cluster_mode`: Try with value `max`, PM2 will auto-detect the number of required processes to run.